# What is the best way to test View Model that depends on child view models?

Tags: c#, testing, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have class `MainViewModel` that takes couple of child view models as dependency. I want to test `MainViewModel` methods. What is the best way to do it? How should I mock child view models?

My code looks like:

```
public class MainViewModel:ViewModelBase
{       
    public MainViewModel(ChildViewModel1 childViewModel1, ChildViewModel2 childViewModel2)
    {
        this.ChildViewModel1 = childViewModel1;
        this.ChildViewModel2 = childViewModel2;
    }

    public ChildViewModel1 ChildViewModel1 { get; set; }

    public ChildViewModel2 ChildViewModel2 { get; set; } 

    public void MethodThatIWantToTest()
    {
        this.ChildViewModel1.SomeProperty = "new value";
    }
}

public class ChildViewModel1:ViewModelBase
{
    private ISomeService someService;

    public ChildViewModel1(ISomeService someService)
    {
        this.someService = someService;
    }

    public string SomeProperty { get; set;}
}


//Test
public void Should_ChangeChildViewModel1SomeProperty_WhenCallingMethodThatIWantToTest()
{
    // arrange
    var mainViewModel = new MainViewModel(.., ..); // how to mock here??

    // act
    mainViewModel.MethodThatIWantToTest();

    // assert
    Assert.Equal(mainViewModel.ChildViewModel1.SomeProperty, "new value");
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for a [mocking framework](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) or just asking for code example ?

Comment: I'm asking for code example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
public void Should_ChangeChildViewModel1SomeProperty_WhenCallingMethodThatIWantToTest()
{
    // arrange -- IService is null because we don't mock 
    //   things that are not being used anyway
    var child1 = new ChildViewModel1(null)

    // act -- childViewModel2 is null because we don't mock 
    //   things that are not being used anyway
    new MainViewModel(child1, null).MethodThatIWantToTest();

    // assert -- access child1 directly instead of through the
    //   property MainViewModel.ChildViewModel1, because this
    //   makes the test more decoupled (fewer assumptions about
    //   MainViewModel class). You could however create a test
    //   checking that the ChildViewModel1 passed to the ctor
    //   really is returned by the property.
    Assert.Equal(child1.SomeProperty, "new value");
}
```

Comment: it is actually what I have done, but I think maybe there is some better solution

Comment: if test method will be more complicated and for example call some childViewModel1 method and so on

Comment: Then you should change your question to reflect that case. Setting a property on a view model is something very different from calling a method on a view model that is being misused as a service.

Answer (score 1):

Dependencies should **not** be concrete classes, they should be **abstractions**.

So in your case, your `ChildViewModels` should implement an `interface` and your `MainViewModel` should depend on the interfaces.

```
public interface IChild1
{
    string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}

...

public MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public IChild1 ChildViewModel1 { get; set; }
    public IChild2 ChildViewModel2 { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel(IChild1 child1, IChild2 child2)
    {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

You can then inject **mocked objects** using a framework like [NSubstitute](http://nsubstitute.github.io/) into the `MainViewModel` when testing.

```
IChild1 child1 = Substitute.For<IChild1>();
IChild2 child2 = Substitute.For<IChild2>();

MainViewModel vm = new MainViewModel(child1, child2);
```

Comment: hm, so I should create interface or abstract class for child view model. That seems strange.

Comment: This design pattern is the **D** in [SOLID design principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)), see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle), *"one should “Depend upon Abstractions. Do not depend upon concretions.”"*. Although I do agree, at first glance it does appear to be pretty stupid. I would recommend reading up on SOLID design principles and patterns.

Comment: hm, you know, I think from design point of view, it is better not to have any child view models. And every View Model should communicate with another one through messaging. That will help us to follow **D** principle.

Answer (score 0):

The "best" way is to not test the child objects and have them mocked or faked and then the child objects should have their own tests. The child objects should be public properties as an *interface* and the test should then inject a mock or fake object.

Fakes are interesting as you can just stub the methods and properties. You must work from an interface though.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/680551/Visual-studio-Fakes

Mocking is another way and you can inherit from the child object class as a parent and set it in the test. Set the object to override and perform as need be by the unit under test. It is quite easy to set up for both happy and bad paths of testing with mocks or fakes.